# Are variables static/extern by default in C?

Tags: c

A simple question;
I know that function are `extern` by default in C. How about variables?

```
int a = 0;

int main(){
 int b = 1;
 return a+b;
}
```

Are `a` and `b` static/extern by default, or they don't have any storage specifiers if nothing is specified.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `a` is defined outside the function.  It is visible outside the current translation unit (TU) if the other TU contains `extern int a;`.

The variable `b` is defined inside the function.  It is an automatic variable that is not visible outside the function.

See C11 [§6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.1) for information about scopes.  The variable `a` has file scope; the variable `b` has block scope.

See also [§6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.2) for information about linkage.  The variable `a` has external linkage.  The variable `b` has no linkage.

See also [§6.2.4 Storage durations of objects](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4).  The variable `a` has static storage duration.  The variable `b` has automatic storage duration.